# Синтаксические связи числительного

Tags: синтаксис

Уж раз заговорили о числительных, хотелось бы порассуждать об их сочетаемости. Почему два письма (ед. ч.), но пять писем (мн. ч.), восемь стульев (мн. ч.), а не пять письма или два писем? Почему у числительных один, два есть род (две), а у остальных нет?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Информация из разных источников.
Особые правила сочетания числительных  два, три, четыре с существительными в единственном числе связаны с исторической грамматикой. Названия чисел от 5 до 9 были существительными ж. р. и управляли Р.П. существительных в форме мн. числа, например: пять столов. Сложнее обстояло дело с названиями чисел 2, 3, 4, которые были счетными прилагательными и согласовывались с существительными в роде, числе и падеже, например: три столы. Кроме того, для числа два существовала специальная форма двойственного числа: два стола, а не два столы. 
   К XVI веку в русском языке происходит разрушение категории двойственного числа,  и формы вида два стола  начинают восприниматься как Р.П. ед. числа. Одновременно происходит выравнивание форм для всех трех  числовых наименований.

Можно предположить, что род числительного «два» также связан с тем, что это слово было прилагательным.  А слово «один» - это грамматическое прилагательное, которое по значению может быть числительным, прилагательным  или местоимением.

Comment: Ну да, http://gramota.ru/spravka/letters/?rub=rubric_92, интересно и то, что это только в русском, в других восточных языках этого нет, ведь это был северо-восточный диалект,в русском литературном языке много лексики пришло из диалектов,а теперь вот оказывается, что и синтаксис имеется диалектный.

Comment: София, Все правильно. Могу добавить только, что форма двойственного числа в древнерусском изначально относилась только к парным предметам. "Рога" там или "ноги".  
  
Не знаю, о каких "восточных" языках говорит Людмила. Сравнивать славянские имеет смысл как раз с "западными", как большей частью  индоевропейскими. Во всех же славянских, включая, естественно, и восточнославянские, происхождение числительных общее, значит общие и проблемы. Другое дело, что в западно-славянских "проблемы" эти не так себя проявляют.

Comment: >Мы всѣ учились понемногу,  
Чему нибудь и какъ нибудь:  
Такъ воспитаньемъ, слава Богу,  
У насъ немудрено блеснуть.  
Онѣгинъ былъ, по мнѣнью многихъ  
(Судей рѣшительныхъ и строгихъ),  
Ученый малый, но педантъ.  
Имѣлъ онъ счастливый талантъ  
Безъ принужденья въ разговорѣ  
Коснуться до всего слегка,  
Съ ученымъ видомъ знатока  
Хранить молчанье въ важномъ спорѣ,  
И возбуждать улыбку дамъ  
Огнемъ нежданыхъ эпиграммъ.

Comment: > форма двойственного числа в
древнерусском изначально относилась только к
парным предметам. "Рога" там или


>... такоже подобает и всем православным крестьянам руку уставляти и **двема персты крестное знамение на лице своем воображати** и покланятися... Ащели **кто двема персты не благословляет**, якоже и Христос, или не воображает крестного знамения, да будет проклят... (Стоглав)  
>Тогда ирод видев, яко поруган бысть от волхвов, разгневася зело и послав изби вся дети сущыя в вифлееме и во всех пределех его, **от двою лету** и нижайше, по времени, еже известно испыта от волхвов. (Мф, 2-16)

Comment: >А мостьнику ехати самому съ отрокомъ **на дву коню** (Русская Правда, 1282)