# Падежи существительных при разных числительных

Tags: падежи, числительные, управление, число, существительные

Есть такое предложение:

*Она покупает пять больших **бутылок сока** и одну маленькую **бутылку вина**.*

Слова ***вина*** и ***сока*** находятся в родительном падеже(нет чего?).

А вот со словом "бутылка" интереснее: ***бутылок*** находится в родительном падеже(нет чего?), ***бутылку*** — в винительном(вижу что?).

Слова выполняют одинаковую функцию, но используются в разных падежах.
Как можно объяснить зависимость падежа от числа существительного?

Comment: Надо исправить: Слова выполняют одинаковую функцию, но используются в разном падеже.

Comment: ... но используются в разных падежах.

Answer (score 2):

Фактически речь идет о склонении числительных и сочетаемости числительных с существительными. Эта тема разбиралась [здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/27214/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE), а также на [Грамоте](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/61-rubric-92).

Глагол *покупает* управляет винительным падежом числительного *пять* (покупает пять). Числительное *пять* управляет существительным, стоящим в форме родительного падежа множественного числа (пять бутылок).

Числительное *один* - это грамматическое прилагательное, поэтому глагол *покупает* 
управляет не числительным *один*, а винительным падежом существительного *бутылка* (покупает бутылку), а числительное *один* согласуется с существительным *бутылка* как прилагательное (одну бутылку).

Comment: Почему в ответе  о д и н,  а не  о д н а?

Comment: @shampar По-моему, при объяснениях нужно называть основную форму - один. А одна - это один в женском роде.

Comment: Небольшая поправка: Числительное пять управляет существительным, стоящим в форме родительного падежа множественного числа (пять бутылок).

Comment: «нужно называть основную форму»... Смешно, когда не числительное согласуется с существительным, а «один» согласуется с «бутылка».

Comment: @Arina, Спасибо! Исправил на *управляет*